# How to stream media playing in songbird?

Tags: linux, streaming, media, songbird

Songbird is an open source media player with lot of plugins. I want to broadcast media playing on my songbird over a network. Kindly, do not suggest me using another player.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pulseaudio` as your audio framework - it has support for acting as a streaming server.  It can play to both your local speakers and a network destination simultaneously.

Comment: How about if I want to do it on windows.Pulseaudio has a lot of problems in windows. Can someone give help on using virtual audio cable?

Comment: @san8055: See, I was tricked by your clever use of the "Linux" tag into thinking this had something to do with Linux.  Pulseaudio does run on Windows.  I don't know what a "virtual audio cable" is.

Comment: Not a problem, at least i got it configured on linux. Thanks to you :) 
Virtual Audio cable is a virtual hardware that can capture you audio from sound card and use it for any purpose like streaming, mixing etc. Wiki for VAC helped me to get it working. Sadly it is a commercial software, but worth buying.